# Having a problem with this method of creating a tooltip using Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, tooltip

Our assignment is to watch the following video and using the author's method, create an HTML list, create a tooltip using Javascript for each list item and *style the tooltip with CSS*.

The video create tooltips for hyperlinks and I just needed to change it so the tooltip is for list items. Sounds simple but I'm having one problem; my CSS works for everything BUT the class tooltip.* *The tooltip only shows up with default styling.* Please help me figure out why.

Here's the video:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ylWto93_rZM
```

and here's my code:

```
https://codepen.io/janicefore/pen/wvqmBOV


var Tooltip = {
opening: function() {
var theList = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
        
if ( theList ) {
for(var i = 0; i < theList.length; i++) {
if( theList[i].title.length) {
theList[i].addEventListener("mouseover", Tooltip.showTip);
theList[i].addEventListener("mouseover", Tooltip.hideTip);
}
                
}
}
},
        
showTip: function( event ) {
var spanElm = document.createElement( "span" );
spanElm.className = "tooltip";
spanElm.innerHTML = event.target.title;
        
event.target.title "";
event.target.appendChild( spanElm ); 
event.target._spanRef = spanElm;
},
        
hideTip: function ( event ) {
event.target.title = event.target._spanRef.innerHTML;
event.target.removeChild( event.target._spanRef );
};
        
window.addEventListener( "load", Tooltip.opening);
```

Comment: Codepen is reporting lots of errors with your code (that red exclamation mark in the circle). For example, you're missing a `}` for `Tooltip`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. javascript typo: mouseover -> mouseout
2. javascript syntax error: `event.target.title "";`
3. javascript syntax error: missing `}` for `Tooltip = {`

Comment: Thank you for pointing out those error's. They definitely will help me get there, however the same problem persists. The tooltip still shows up with default styling; without the CSS I applied.  I'm guessing it must have something to do with the showTip function where I create the span with the className "tooltip"  My CSS does not recognize the class tooltip.

Comment: P.S. I addressed those errors in my codepen:
https://codepen.io/janicefore/pen/wvqmBOV

Comment: It works with `.tooltip` in the CSS.  my codepen: https://codepen.io/sdkn104/pen/gOxzRLP

Comment: I posted the original request for help.  I'd like to thank "hashed tomato" for helping me solve my problem!!!  I don't understand how everything works yet but if I need to do anything else to give you credit, please let me know.  It's wonderful to have the support of a coding community.  Thank you.